# C# Code execution takes very long

Tags: c#

I'm running this code and it freezes my program for a while to fill the Textbox. Is there a way to do it faster? Or if it is not possible to make it faster by running in background so I can continue using the program?

```
        var numbers = "0123456789";
        var q = numbers.Select(x => x.ToString());
        int size = 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
            q = q.SelectMany(x => numbers, (x, y) => x + y);

        foreach (var item in q)
        {
           //Console.WriteLine(item);
            textBox.Text += item + Environment.NewLine;
        }
```

Comment: You could run this code on a background worker thread (or use await/async) which would prevent your UI from freezing.

Comment: Any long running task should be done on a separate thread (not on the UI thread)!

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint to determine where it's continously looping?

Comment: You can run any code in a background thread using [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a background worker will not solve the underlying problem; you're not filling the textbox correctly.

By using the `+=` string operator directly in a loop, you're using [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm), which is highly inefficient.

You can solve this by using StringBuilder and only show the end result in the textbox:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in q)
{
    sb.Append(item + Environment.NewLine);
}   

textBox.Text += sb.ToString();
```

Iterating over your 10k numbers shouldn't take more than a few milliseconds, at most.

Comment: On my machine using the `StringBuilder` is meaningless, and it seems not very surprising for such a trivial task. The main improvement comes from not updating the `Text` property multiple number of times.

Comment: @BartoszKP Using SB instead of the normal concatenation on my machine reduces the time from 120ms to 2ms (Let's say 12, because of StopWatch's imprecision), which is still 10x better. And if `size` become 5, 6 or 10 it'll become even more a real bottleneck.

Comment: Yes, indeed you're right. I did some more thorough measurements (details in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

The main problem seems concatenating the strings directly to the control, which refreshes itself on each modification of its `Text` property. Try this version:

```
var result = string.Empty;
foreach (var item in q)
{
    result += item + Environment.NewLine;
}

textBox.Text = result;
```

You could also use [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but on my machine difference was meaningless (**EDIT :** apparently not, details below). And of course you should in general use [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for heavy computations. This is the boundary case IMHO for modern machines.

As a follow-up on discussion with [Pierre-Luc Pineault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2316200/pierre-luc-pineault) under [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21290189/2642204) I did some measurements, and this is what came out:

```
StringBuilder average: 0,9336, stddev: 0,591938375170962 [ms]
String average: 61,9763, stddev: 7,17896498877082        [ms]
```

So yes, indeed you should use `StringBuilder` even in this case:

```
var result = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in q)
{
    result.Append(item + Environment.NewLine);
}

textBox.Text = result.ToString();
```

Here is the code I've used to make the measurements:

```
class Test
{
    private static Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    public static int st()
    {
        var numbers = "0123456789";
        var q = numbers.Select(x => x.ToString());
        int size = 4;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
            q = q.SelectMany(x => numbers, (x, y) => x + y);

        String s = "";
        foreach (var item in q)
            s += item;

        return s.Length;
    }

    public static int sb()
    {
        var numbers = "0123456789";
        var q = numbers.Select(x => x.ToString());
        int size = 4;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
            q = q.SelectMany(x => numbers, (x, y) => x + y);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in q)
            sb.Append(item);

        return sb.ToString().Length;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        int n = 100000;
        List<long> sbSamples = new List<long>(n);
        List<long> stSamples = new List<long>(n);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            sb();
            sw.Stop();
            sbSamples.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            st();
            sw.Stop();
            stSamples.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

        double sbAv = 1.0 * sbSamples.Sum() / sbSamples.Count;
        double stAv = 1.0 * stSamples.Sum() / sbSamples.Count;
        double sbStdDev = Math.Sqrt(sbSamples.Select(x
            => (x - sbAv) * (x - sbAv)).Sum() / sbSamples.Count);
        double stStdDev = Math.Sqrt(stSamples.Select(x
            => (x - stAv) * (x - stAv)).Sum() / stSamples.Count);

        Console.WriteLine(
            "StringBuilder average: " + sbAv + ", stddev: " + sbStdDev);
        Console.WriteLine(
            "String average: " + stAv + ", stddev: " + stStdDev);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: I chose Pierre-Luc answer, but your answer alsol solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: How do you do this measurements?